# How to handle employees with poor job etiquette?

Tags: manager, termination

I work at a community college and I recently fired a part-time employee who I believe had very poor job etiquette. The employee and I worked very closely together for about 4-6 months. In that time, he had many occassions of asking for time off, asking to come in later 15 minutes before his shift, and was late to work often. He also disreguarded several e-mails from my supervisors in regards to policies and procedures.

I feel like since I worked closely with him, that I failed in correcting his behaviors. Since he was the first employee that I had ever trained for the job I may have been too relaxed and more focused on being a "cool" manager. I did make sure to let him know when he was doing something wrong WITHIN the job, however it was hard for me to bring up things like when he asked 15 minutes before his shift, to come in 4 hours later because he had to run "errands".

Some of his reasons for being late and his tardiness baffled me. I did not know how to bring up these things that I would already expect my employees to know not to do. I think I was ok in correcting any job function related behaviors, but could not find a way to bring up job etiquette matters since to me they were "common sense".

Since I feel like I did not communicate well enough with him, I feel guilty that we fired him. Although I do not believe that he was the correct fit for the job, I want to know how to communicate better as a supervisor in the future.

Comment: Voting to close as I'm unsure what the actual question is?  What do you expect to achieve from an answer, re-assurance, or some specific advice?  As it is, it's more looking for a hug, which isn't a good fit for the site.

Comment: Ok I updated the question. I'm looking for advice from other managers on how to deal with employees that don't have a good sense of general job etiquette

Comment: I've re-worded the question entirely and think it might be more clear. Thank you

Comment: Do not feel guilty. Being a manager is just like any other job. Something you need to learn. Just learn from it (and you being here means you want to).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take the emotion out of it.  Your job is to ensure the company runs smoothly.  Address difficulties immediately.  If the employee is late, right into your office discussing the consequences if it happens again.

If you are swift, consistent, firm, and fair with the discipline early on, it does not become a problem later.  Communicate with your staff frequently and let them know EXACTLY where they stand.

The problem with being "cool" until a problem is starting to become a big one is that you are then in a position where little corrections are no longer an option.

Remember Discipline should be:

- Early
- Often
- Consistent
- Fair

Once that has been established, and the employees know what is expected of them and what consequences, good and bad, await them, you can step back.

Comment: yep, make the boundaries known early and be consistent.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere you can use the word "coaching" in your answer.  I won't include newspeak in mine.